# How to get the strings out of this?

Tags: php, string

I am trying to get some specific values out of the following string:

```
{"car":"Toyota"{"car":"honda"{"car":"BMW{"car":"Hyundai"
```

I want to get '`Toyota`' out of that. The string is randomly generated, so it could be `Benz` or `Pontiac`.

Comment: You want to get the first car?  Or all cars?

Comment: Is this supposed to be some corrupt JSON ?

Comment: That is nearly JSON. Is it originally JSON? If so, has it been corrupted, have you done some replacements, or have you simply mistyped the example in the question?

Comment: Agreed -- what is this string? It is irregular... sometimes the curly brace is in a quote, sometimes not? Almost impossible to parse.

Comment: @Chris that appears to be a typo, with "BMW" missing its ending quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what this crazy string is from, but if you've accurately shown the format, this will extract the strings you're after:

```
$string = '{"car":"Toyota"{"car":"honda"{"car":"BMW{"car":"Hyundai"';
$string = array_filter(
    explode(',', 
        preg_replace(
            array('/"/', '/{/', '/:/', '"car"'),
            array('', ',',  '', ''),
            $string
        )
    )
);
print_r($string);
// Output: Array ( [1] => Toyota [2] => honda [3] => BMW [4] => Hyundai )
```

... if, instead, this is just a horrible typeo and this is supposed to be JSON, use `json_decode`:

```
$string = '[{"car":"Toyota"},{"car":"honda"},{"car":"BMW"},{"car":"Hyundai"}]'; // <-- valid JSON
$data = json_decode($string, true);
print_r($data);
// Output: Array ( [0] => Array ( [car] => Toyota ) [1] => Array ( [car] => honda ) [2] => Array ( [car] => BMW ) [3] => Array ( [car] => Hyundai ) )
```

**Documentation**

- `preg_replace` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php
- `array_filter` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php
- `explode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php
- `json_decode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Comment: @chris: preg_replace when it's not needed. I'm sure you aimed for something different the first place, but within that code-chunk it's superfluous.

Comment: What does that even mean? Superfluous, as opposed to several calls to `str_replace`, or some other fragile collection of explodes? It does the job, there's no reason *not* to use it. I am unaware of any best-practice guideline that suggests one should be conservative with `preg_replace` in favor of other methods... source?

Answer (score 1):

Although this looks like a corrupt piece of JSON, I would say you can get the first car with explode().

```
$string = '{"car":"Toyota"{"car":"honda"{"car":"BMW{"car":"Hyundai"';
$string = explode("{", $string);
$firstcar = $string[1]; //your string starts with {, so $string[0] would be empty
$firstcar = explode(":", $firstcar);
$caryouarelookingfor = $firstcar[1]; // [0] would be 'car', [1] will be 'Toyota'
echo $caryouarelookingfor // output: "Toyota"
```

But, as also mentioned in the comments, the string looks like a corrupt piece of JSON, so perhaps you want to fix the construction of this string. :)

EDIT: typo in code, as said in first comment.

Comment: This method is very fragile, and the output is `"Toyota"` (note the quotes).